# Applying an overlay (image filter) to a Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, png, overlay, android-camera

I am trying to capture an image from the camera intent and then apply an image filter on it. To elaborate the image would be an image captured by the camera and the image filter would be available in the resources as a png file. I am able to overlay the  filter on top of the original image. But, once overlay-ed the original image is 'almost' invisible (which means that the filter is infact being stacked on the original image and not merely replacing it). I have a couple of images to illustrate my problem. The first image was in Photoshop - when I placed a filter on top of an image, it seemed just fine. The second image is the produced by the code cited below - you can clearly see that the filter effect is missing. Would someone have a clue as to why something like this is occurring. Am I missing some logic here?

[image: Filterd Image - Photoshop]

[image: Filtered Image - via code]

**The following is the code that I have. I apologize if you find any best practices missing here. I am initially trying to test the code:**

```
mPictureView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureView);
filterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filter_button1);

// define the threshold fro scaling the image
private final double SCALE_THRESHOLD = 6.0;

// acquire the bitmap (photo captured) from the Camera Intent - the uri is 
// passed from a previous activity that accesses the camera and the current 
// activity is used to display the bitmap
Uri imageUri = getIntent().getData();
Bitmap imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

// set the imageView in the current activity to display the picture retrieved 
// from the camera
mPictureView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

// get the dimensions of the original bitmap
int photoWidth = imageBitmap.getWidth();
int photoHeight = imageBitmap.getHeight();

filterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // set the options
    Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    // get the image (png file) filter from resources using the options
    Bitmap filter = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.colorful_filter,options);

    // create a scaled copy of the filter
    Bitmap filtercopy = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(filter, (int)(photoWidth/SCALE_THRESHOLD,(int)(photoHeight/SCALE_THRESHOLD), true);

    // recycle the used bitmap
    filter.recycle();
    filter = null;

    // get a scaled, mutable copy of the orginial image 
    Bitmap imagecopy = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap,(int)(photoWidth/SCALE_THRESHOLD), (int)(photoHeight/SCALE_THRESHOLD),true);

    // recycle the used bitmap      
    imageBitmap.recycle();
    imageBitmap = null;


    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    //paint.setAlpha(230); - if a discrete value is set, then the image beneath 
    // the filter is visible. But, I don't understand why I need to do this. 
    // Besides, that reduces the efficacy of the filter

    // create a canvas with the original image as the underlying image      
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(imagecopy);
    // now, draw the filter on top of the bitmap
    canvas.drawBitmap(filtercopy, 0, 0, paint);

    // recycle the used bitmap              
    filtercopy.recycle();
    filtercopy = null;

    //set the filtered bitmap as the image
    mPictureView.setImageBitmap(imagecopy);

}
```

**EDIT 1: I was able to make some progress with the help of the article that Joru has provided. The problem seems to be with blending of the 2 bitmaps. The method drawBitmap would just draw one bitmap over the other in the situation that I have. The following line of code will actually attempt to blend the 2 bitmaps. I have also attached an image which depicts my progress. The underlying bitmap is noticeably more visible now:**

```
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));
```

**I have to still play around with it for some time, before achieving the desired output.**[image: Color Filter - Revisited]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a few things:

```
Bitmap new = old.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

To make sure the bitmap you are opening from `MediaStore` is in that format. If it isn't, that is likely to cause your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reponse. I have already ensured that both the images are in ARGB_8888 format. It seems like the filter is losing some transparency and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Reading this http://android.nakatome.net/2010/04/bitmap-basics.html may be of help.

Comment: This article was very helpful. I have infused some of the ideas presented there into my code and it has shown positive yet not complete results. So, I will continue to work on it and post a solution as soon as I figure it out. Thanks again - I am accepting your answer since you have pointed me in the right direction.